# Reading from a text file throws exception

Tags: java, eclipse, loading, save

So I've used DataInputStream, FileInputStream, BufferInputStream, FileReader, BufferedReader, Scanner, you name it. They all throw FileNOtFoundException or CorruptedStreamException.

the exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileReader@253498.data (The system cannot find the file specified) 
gets thrown on the line where the FileReader is initialized with the filename "Accounts.txt", which is a file that i HAVE initialized, in the bin, with the text needed in it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Class to load account files
 */
public class AccountLoader {

    /**
     * Add an account file
     * @param newAccount 
     */
    public static void addAcountFile(Account newAccount) {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("Accounts.txt"));

            out.print(" " + newAccount.getOwner().getName());
            System.out.println("saved account " + newAccount.getOwner().getName());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static ArrayList<Account> loadAccountsList() throws EOFException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList();

            FileReader load = new FileReader("Accounts.txt");

            String file = load.toString();

           String[] accountsload = file.split(" ");
           for (String string : accountsload){
               accounts.add(loadAccount(string + ".data"));
           }
           load.close();
           return accounts;

    }
    public static void save(Account account) {

        String filename = account.getOwner().getName() + ".data" ; 
            if (filename != null) {         
          try {
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename); 

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 


            out.writeObject(account);    

            out.flush();                    
            out.close();                        
          }

          catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }

      }

     public static Account loadAccount(String filename) {   
           Account newAccount = null;
            if (filename != null) {           
              try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename); 

                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  

                newAccount = (Account)in.readObject();
                in.close();                                     
              }

              catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
            return newAccount;
          }

}
```

Comment: Are you using command line to run?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you're not looking for the file in the correct location, the user directory, just like 99% of the folks who ***frequently*** ask this very same question (if I had a quarter for every time...). Find the user directory by running this line: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if I had a quarter for every time you were right...

Comment: What are the odds! (1%, by your estimate) it's actually in the same folder that System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); prints. But that's my fault for not telling you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put the text file in the "project root" folder (the one that contains `src` and `bin`), not the `bin` folder. If you're running this from Eclipse that's definitely what you need to do, since the context for Java projects run from Eclipse is always the Eclipse project folder for that project.

When you ask Java to open a file by name without giving it a path, the JVM will look for the file in its current working directory. The current working directory changes depending on how you run the program, and in your case it looks like the "bin" folder is not your current working directory.

Comment: it's in the project root folder, actually. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the text file to some other folders. One folder out of the bin folder is probably the right location.

Comment: Woops, I lied. It's in the folder one step out of the bin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command line, put the file in the folder from where you are running the java command and add `.` in the CLASSPATH as

```
  set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.
```

and then run your java program.

If you are using eclipse, try putting the file in root folder of the project or use the relative path with respect to root folder.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, and the file is in the root folder.

Comment: By `root` folder, I mean the project folder not the `src` or `JavaSource`. Is it there in project folder(parent of src folder)?

Comment: yes. and anyway the folder was saved in the first place from this class, so the working directory would have to be the same, right?

Comment: Eclipse treats the working directory as project root folder not the folder where ".class" file is present. I have so many working examples where I have put the files in my project folder e.g. "TestJava" while java files are in "TestJava/JavaSource/com/test/concept/" folder and all are working without any issues.

Comment: @user1253476 - I got an idea. Try creating a file e.g. `output.txt` using `FileWriter` and check the location of the file being created. I am quite sure, it would be different that the one you are using for file read.